# Magento 2: on declined payment set order status pending and cancel invoice

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, invoice

On declined payment stop invoice generation and set order state in pending

```
public function capture(\Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface $payment, $amount)
        {
          $order = $payment->getOrder();
           try {
              if($charge):
                $payment->setTransactionId($charge["id"]);
                if ($capture) {
                    $payment->setIsTransactionClosed(1);
                } else {
                    $payment->setIsTransactionClosed(0);
                } else:


                endif;
            } catch ( $e) {

                $error_code = $e->getErrorCode();
                if ($error_code === "card_declined") {
                    $errorMsg = 'Charge was declined. Please, contact you bank for more information or use a different card.';
                } else {
                    $errorMsg = $e->getMessage();
                }
$this->_logger->error(__($errorMsg));
$orderId=$order->getId();
            $payment->setSkipTransactionCreation(true);
                 //throw new \Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception(__($errorMsg));

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two function did the trick for  me

**$payment->setIsTransactionPending(true);**

**$payment->setIsFraudDetected(true);**

```
public function capture(\Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface $payment, $amount)
        {
          $order = $payment->getOrder();
           try {
              if($charge):
                $payment->setTransactionId($charge["id"]);
                if ($capture) {
                    $payment->setIsTransactionClosed(1);
                } else {
                    $payment->setIsTransactionClosed(0);
                } else:


                endif;
            } catch ( $e) {

                $error_code = $e->getErrorCode();
                if ($error_code === "card_declined") {
                    $errorMsg = 'Charge was declined. Please, contact you bank for more information or use a different card.';
                } else {
                    $errorMsg = $e->getMessage();
                }
$this->_logger->error(__($errorMsg));
$orderId=$order->getId();
            $payment->setSkipTransactionCreation(true);
                 //throw new \Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception(__($errorMsg));
            $state = 'pending_payment';
            $status = 'pending_payment';
            $comment = $errorMsg;
            $isNotified = false;
            $order->setState($state);
            $order->setStatus($status);
            $order->addStatusToHistory($order->getStatus(), $comment);
            $order->save(); 
            $payment->setIsTransactionPending(true); 
            $payment->setIsFraudDetected(true);

            }
```