# How to change order status after payment

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, payment

I need to change order status to custom status if payment fails.

I tried to get order via `$payment->getOrder()`, and tried to set state and status. I called `save()` also. However It looks like not working. It is always saving order with 'processing' status. However, It saves comments when I run following functions using same method; `addStatusToHistory`, `addStatusHistoryComment`. Any idea how can I implement this?

```
class Payment extends \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\Cc {
...
fn(){
$payment->getOrder()->setState( 'holded' )->setStatus( 'custom_new_status' )->save();
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
        $state = 'holded';
        $status = 'custom_new_status';
        $comment = '';
        $order->setState($state);
        $order->setStatus($status);
        $order->addStatusToHistory($order->getStatus(), $comment);
        $order->save();
```

[Reference](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/174479/magneto-2-on-declined-payment-set-order-status-pending-and-cancel-invoice)

Comment: Hi, thanks for quick answer. I already tried, but It didn't work.

Comment: You can Use Event and Observer concept.Once payment has been completed observer can be called where you can set the order custom status @MmtBkn

Comment: Thanks @PranayK, I'm aware of it but thought should be easier way to do it.

Comment: @MmtBkn you should check your order object first.

Comment: @QaisarSatti there is order object. I can add comment to history, however something is overriding and changing status to processing

Comment: @MmtBkn you have to add status after creating the invoice.

Comment: @QaisarSatti Invoiceing is handled by different accounting software. I didn't try.